# How do I get the achievement for Sector 3?

Tags: achievements, qube

In Q.U.B.E., how do I get the achievement "Sector 3, Completed"? I have completed all 7 sectors, and I got all of the corresponding achievements except the one for sector 3. I then played through sector 3 again and I still did not get the achievement. Do I have to do anything besides simply proceeding linearly as usual to get the achievement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2468401) posted by one of the developers on the Steam forums, the achievement for sector 3 is broken and will not unlock, along with

- Finale
- Find the Developers
- Tough Going Part 1
- Tough Going Part 2
- Fizzicks

**EDIT**: The achievements appear to be fixed. The achievement for Sector 3 can now be obtained simply by playing through the sector like with all of the other achievements. I tested and every one of the previously broken achievements can now be obtained.

Comment: From that threat:  *"You will need to replay the levels in order to get the locked achievements"* :(

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft right, and we still have to wait for a patch